# Horizontal xtable on summary of data from read.csv

Tags: r, xtable

I've got a CSV file that looks like this:

```
RTT,From,Req,Bytes,TTL
202,10.0.0.10,1,64,64
191,10.0.0.10,2,64,64
...
```

I am trying to produce a LaTeX `summary()` using `library(xtable)`, like so:

```
library(xtable)
pings <- read.csv("pings.csv")
s <- summary(pings$RTT)
xtable(t(s))
```

This produces the output:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrr}
  \hline
 & Min. & 1st Qu. & Median & Mean & 3rd Qu. & Max. \\
  \hline
1 & 40.70 & 42.70 & 43.40 & 44.90 & 44.10 & 202.00 \\
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

This is *almost* what I want, except for the first column containing an empty value and `1`.

Clearly, I'm missing some vital, basic knowledge about data types and conversions in R. The problem is of course that `t(s)` produces:

```
      Min. 1st Qu. Median  Mean 3rd Qu.  Max.
[1,]  40.7    42.7   43.4  44.9    44.1 202.0
```

wherein the `[,1]` should explain xtable's output.

Can anyone please point out to me what I'm doing wrong?

If I'm simply trying to run xtable on the summary, I get

```
> xtable(summary(pings$RTT))
Error in xtable.table(summary(pings$RTT)) : 
  xtable.table is not implemented for tables of > 2 dimensions
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is handled by `print.xtable()`:

```
> library(xtable)
> print.xtable(xtable(t(summary(runif(10)))), include.rownames=FALSE)
% latex table generated in R 3.0.2 by xtable 1.7-3 package
% Sat Apr 26 20:03:32 2014
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrr}
  \hline
Min. & 1st Qu. & Median & Mean & 3rd Qu. & Max. \\ 
  \hline
0.03 & 0.18 & 0.48 & 0.41 & 0.61 & 0.74 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Here `include.rownames=FALSE` disables outputting row names. See `?print.xtable` for more details.

Comment: I laughed when you removed the methods list. Looks like we are both trying to avoid overlapping details.

Comment: You were the first who did that :)

Answer (score 3):

`xtable` was fist developed for tables, in particular for  2 dimensional contingency tables, and then extended to various other output that might come in this way. It was never extended to objects of summaryDefault class which is what your `s` object is. When you coerce it to a matrix with `t` it becomes a 2 dimensional object and it then gets coerces to a dataframe with one rowname, "1" which gets printed by default. @gagolews gave you the way to get around it although I thought the help pages for xtable were a bit skimpy on details. It is helpful to look at the code. although most of it is hidden:

```
> methods(xtable)
 [1] xtable.anova*           xtable.aov*             xtable.aovlist*        
 [4] xtable.coxph*           xtable.data.frame*      xtable.glm*            
 [7] xtable.lm*              xtable.matrix*          xtable.prcomp*         
[10] xtable.summary.aov*     xtable.summary.aovlist* xtable.summary.glm*    
[13] xtable.summary.lm*      xtable.summary.prcomp*  xtable.table*          
[16] xtable.ts*              xtable.zoo*            

   Non-visible functions are asterisked
> getAnywhere(xtable.matrix)
A single object matching ‘xtable.matrix’ was found
It was found in the following places
  registered S3 method for xtable from namespace xtable
  namespace:xtable
with value

function (x, caption = NULL, label = NULL, align = NULL, digits = NULL, 
    display = NULL, ...) 
{
    return(xtable.data.frame(data.frame(x, check.names = FALSE), 
        caption = caption, label = label, align = align, digits = digits, 
        display = display))
}
<environment: namespace:xtable>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Aside, I tried the `stargazer` library, and it worked.

Comment: +1 for `methods()`. Note that there is no `xtable.default` function, so any other object type is unsupported.

Comment: Yeah. The rerror message he got was from `xtable.table` which was how I inferred that it was the 'original 'function.

Comment: Wish I could upvote more. Thanks for the thorough explanation.

Comment: Don't worry. I would have given you another upvote for mentioning the stargazer package.